# Limits - Rigorous Approach

Tags: limits, terminology

In this question $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac {1}{(x-2)} = 0$

How does 1 divide to the other side

$\frac {1}{(x-2)} \lt \epsilon \qquad$ if $x \gt N$

$x-2 < \frac 1 \epsilon if x \gt N$

Comment: Somehow you have reversed the sense of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

if $N \ge 2$, then $x-2 > 0$.

From $\frac1{x-2} < \epsilon$, multiply both sides by $x-2$.

$$1< \epsilon(x-2)$$

Now divide both sides by $\epsilon > 0$, and you will get the result.

Remark: The inequality sign is flipped.